# Gmail sends EHLO..QUIT immediately to custom SMTP/MTA server

Tags: c++, linux, smtp, mail-server

I'm trying to write a simple receiving mail server (MTA) in C++ on Linux, I've gotten as far as when I try to send mail to it from my Gmail account, a Google server connects, but then quits right after. I have no idea what I'm missing. The current communication looks like:

```
S: 220 mx.domain.com ESMTP<CR><LF>
C: EHLO mail.google.com<CR><LF>QUIT<CR><LF>
S: 250 mx.domain.com at your service<CR><LF>221 Bye<CR><LF>
```

I'm very confused by the fact the Google mail server is sending both EHLO and QUIT in the same request. And of course it never sends the actual mail. Any ideas as to why it quits?

Comment: See [RFC 2821: Simply Mail Transport Protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt). Use telnet to talk with the SMTP server manually. Good luck.

Comment: You mean talk to his own MTA manually right?

Comment: @Shutupsquare Oh, that *is* harder to deal with I suppose.

Comment: @TheCokeGuy What is the conversation between gmail and {insert a well-known server}?

Comment: @user2864740 Makes a good point though does it work okay with other mail servers? you seem to just pick out googles, did you try telnet?

Comment: My guess would be that Google was simply testing the connection to make sure it was actually connecting to an SMTP server and not to something else.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm already using telnet extensively, it's an invaluable tool :) I wanted to see the comm. between postfix and Google, but I ahve no idea how to "peek" at the connection. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Shutupsquare I've also tried Hotmail, which only connects, but never replies to the 220.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau It might be, but as it "should" have confirmed it to be an SMTP server, why is it not connecting again to send the mail?

Comment: I can see Google keeps trying to connect over and over again, so there must be something making it disconnect and try again later.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if maybe `mx.domain.com` does not match the domain that Google used to determine the server's IP, so it thinks it connected to the wrong server.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau The MX record and the host is the same, I've even made sure it matches the reverse DNS :/

Comment: @TheCokeGuy: Then you will likely have to contact Google directly and ask them what is happening on their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was because the server sent the response to the client padded with '\0' after capping to the correct response length everything works as intended.